# Synergy - Control + Scroll Not Zooming

Tags: synergy, zoom

I am using Synergy, 64 bit, between two Windows computers - A Windows 8 Professional, and a Windows 7 Professional.

The Windows 8 Pro is the server. When Synergy is on, I try to hold down `[control]` and then `[scroll]` up or down on Adobe Reader X, and it does not zoom.

However, If I try to do this on Office 2007 (word), it does zoom.

This is odd, as the functionality randomly works on one program, but not the other.

As soon as I stop the Synergy server, I can zoom on Adobe Reader.

I cannot find anything on this through web searches. Synergy seems very limited on settings and I cannot find anything that handles this. Is there a way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

[Well this sucks.](http://synergy-foss.org/spit/issues/details/3393/?lang=en)

Synergy bug, not yet fixed, I happen to have the perfect setup to reproduce this.